# Data Frame of Factors: Split column into two and extract number

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, `df`, and below is my first column in the data frame as `df[1]` :

```
 Well and Depth  
   Black Peak 1000
   Black Peak 1001
   Black Peak 1002
   Black Peak 1003
```

RStudio is currently treating this column as a list of factors, but I want to split this into two data frame columns/vectors, one with the text as a string/char, and one with the numbers as numeric values. So that it will look something like this:

```
   Well            Depth
   "Black Peak"     1000
   "Black Peak"     1001
   "Black Peak"     1002
   "Black Peak"     1003
```

The depth numbers are going to be plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HERE=data.frame(WELL=character(),DEPTH=numeric())
strcapture("(.*)\\s(\\d+)$",as.character(df[,1]),HERE)
        WELL DEPTH
1 Black Peak  1000
2 Black Peak  1001
3 Black Peak  1002
4 Black Peak  1003
```

Comment: would your solution work if there are digits in between letters? For example: "Black 1000 Peak  1000"?

Comment: No it wont work. I can add `$` at the end to make that work.

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on here. This doesn't call upon my specific data frame. Could you edit this to what I have in my data frame?

Comment: Look at it again it has the name `df[,1]` exactly as you called yours

Comment: Can I just reuse my `df` data frame instead of declaring an entirely new data frame `HERE`? Also, I have additional columns after my first column. How would I insert a new second column (which will be the depth), before the following columns, and put those numbers in the newly inserted column?

Comment: the adittional `HERE` is the `proto` for the function `strcapture`. So you can use a different name but you cannot use the exact name as your `df`. at the same time after this you can just `cbind` the results to your `df`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df$Well  <- sub("(^.*) [0-9]+$", "\\1", df$`Well and Depth`)
df$Depth <- as.numeric(sub(".* ([0-9]+$)", "\\1", df$`Well and Depth`))
```

---

Data:

```
structure(list(`Well and Depth` = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Black Peak 1000", 
"Black Peak 1001", "Black Peak 1002", "Black Peak 1003"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Well and Depth", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm going to have 100+ depths in future cases and won't type out all of the names into one c() vector within the script.

Comment: This answer is useful

Comment: @NotAMathMan what's a "depth"?

Comment: I just mean that I'm going to have a lot more entries than 4 as shown in this example. In the future, I will have 100+ entries of this; as in it'll be Black Rock 1001, Black Rock 1002.....Black Rock 1105. By depth, I simply mean the number 1001, 1002, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` from`tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, `Well and Depth`, into = c("Well", "Depth"), "\\s+(?=[0-9])")
#        Well Depth
#1 Black Peak  1000
#2 Black Peak  1001
#3 Black Peak  1002
#4 Black Peak  1003
```