# Convert data frame column of factor into two usable columns of a string and numerical

Tags: r

I have a data frame, `df` with 17 columns and 60 rows. My first two columns and four rows look like the following:

```
  Well and Depth    Mean 
   Black Peak 1000    500
   Black Peak 1001    600
   Black Peak 1002    700
   Black Peak 1003    800
```

My first "Well and Depth" column is currently a column of factors. I would like to insert two new columns in between the "Well and Depth" and "Mean" Columns. I would like my code to automatically extract the text before the number (i.e.) "1001", "10002, "10003"...etc.) and separately the number value from the "Well and Depth" column and insert it into the newly created columns, which I will call "Well Name" and "Depth". All the text that precedes space before the numbers would be what goes into the "Well Name" column and the number would go into the "depth" column. The first four columns would end up looking like this:

```
  Well and Depth        Well Name      Depth      Mean 
   "Black Peak 1000"     "Black Peak"     1000     500
   "Black Peak 1001"     "Black Peak"     1001     600
   "Black Peak 1002"     "Black Peak"     1002     700
   "Black Peak 1003"     "Black Peak"     1003     800
```

This will involve much larger datasets than 4  rows as shown here, so Ideally I'd like to avoid long vectors of text in the script.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and the one you had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691823/data-frame-of-factors-split-column-into-two-and-extract-number/48692175#48692175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)    

# This generates your data frame, "check.names" allows spaces in names
df <- data.frame("Well and Depth"= c("Black Peak 1000",
                                    "Black Peak 1001",
                                    "Black Peak 1002",
                                    "Black Peak 1003"),
                 "Mean"= c(500, 600, 700, 800),
                 check.names = FALSE)
# Convert to factor
df$`Well and Depth` <- as.factor(df$`Well and Depth`)

# Generate required features   
df %<>%
 mutate(`Well Name` = gsub("(.*\\s)\\d+$", "\\1", `Well and Depth`)) %>%
 mutate(Depth = gsub(".*\\s(\\d+)$", "\\1", `Well and Depth`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your previous question's answer [Data Frame of Factors: Split column into two and extract number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691823/data-frame-of-factors-split-column-into-two-and-extract-number)  as the starting point:

```
#the data
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, text="WellandDepth    Mean 
   'Black Peak 1000'    500
   'Black Peak 1001'    600
   'Black Peak 1002'    700
   'Black Peak 1003'    800")

#split Well and Depth column
HERE=data.frame(WELL=character(),DEPTH=numeric())
HERE<-strcapture("(.*)\\s(\\d+)$",as.character(df[,1]),HERE)

#paste it all back together
answer<-data.frame('Well and Depth'=df[,1], HERE, Mean=df[,2])
```